# Bundler ignoring 'without' group

Tags: ruby, bundler

I'm trying to include gems from my local instead of the gemserver on development. My Gemfile looks like this:

```
group :development do
  gem "appy_core", path: "../engines/core"
end

group :production do
  gem "appy_core", '1.7.4.5'
end
```

My `.bundle/config` is set to:

```
---
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: production
```

Yet when I run `bundle` I get:

```
 [!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements.
 You specified: appy_core (>= 0) and appy_core (= 1.7.4.5). Bundler cannot continue.
```

Running `bundle install --without production` produces the same result.

Comment: The problem is not in ignore the production env, problem is `You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements.`

Comment: @Зелёный: So Bundler won't install the production gems on development, but will still throw an error if the version requirements are different?

Comment: it still throw an error if you specify the same gem twice.

Comment: @Зелёный So what's the solution to the problem? What do people normally do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I came up with / am aware of:

in `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'appy_core', 
    git: 'git://github.com/.......',
    branch: '1.7.4.5' # put the name of the branch that corresponds
```

in local environment’s shell:

```
$ bundle config local.appy_core /path/to/engines/core
```

Now do whatever you want in the local branch, commit it locally and enjoy.

---

**Hack that works**

Since `Gemfile` is plain ruby, one might use ruby features there:

somewhere in permanent shell settings:

```
alias bundle="USE_DEV_VERSION=1 bundle"
```

in `Gemfile`:

```
if ENV['USE_DEV_VERSION']
  gem "appy_core", path: "../engines/core"
else
  gem "appy_core", '1.7.4.5'
end
```

Now `bundle install` will use dev version locally and the standard gem outside of the “patched” environment.

Comment: In my `./bundle/config` I now have `BUNDLE_LOCAL__APPY_CORE: "/Users/daniel/engines/core"`. But when I run `bundle install` it's not using my local source. I did not specify `git` and `branch` in the Gemfile though as the remote source is a gem server.

Comment: 1. How do you know it’s not using the local source? 2. I have no idea how `bundler` treats local settings, it is nearly undocumented feature I discovered occasionally. What prevents you from specifying `git` and `branch`?

Comment: @mudsaobwa 1.Because the version bundler says is installed is not the same as master. 2. Because it's on a gem server, not a git repo.

Comment: 1. Bundler is (AFAIK) able to pick up the version specified in the gem, it should not be `master`. Try to put `binding.pry` or like in the local version and see if it’s stopped there.

Comment: OK, I know another hack, please see an update. Do not use at home and in the school :)

Comment: I thought about that as well, but `config/env.yml` won't run until you start the rails server. Also tried putting an `export RAILS_ENV="development" in `.bash_profile`. But it doesn't work either. Maybe it's an OSX thing.

Comment: Just do `alias bundle="USE_DEV_VERSION=1 bundle"` and run `bundle install`. It will be using dev version locally and standard gem outside of the environment with this shell variable specified.

Comment: Awesome, that works. Please update answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Gemfile` is executed as Ruby code, you can reference `Bundler.settings` directly to explicitly exclude duplicate gems within a group:

```
def without?(group)
  Bundler.settings.without.include?(group)
end

group :development do
  gem "appy_core", path: "../engines/core" unless without? :development
end

group :production do
  gem "appy_core", '1.7.4.5' unless without? :production
end
```